# Read/write only for scripts

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions

Seems it is a question about `.htaccess`, not sure what should I use.

**How can I make files inside `/data/` folder available to `read` and `write` only for scripts?**

Users should not have access to them from browser window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way to block access to non-scripts: move it outside the web server's document root. If your PHP files are served from `/var/www/htdocs`, put your data files in `/var/www/data`.

If that's not possible, the `.htaccess` solution looks like:

```
# don't let anyone access these files directly
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

Comment: Where should I put this file?

Comment: You can put it right in your `data` directory. `.htaccess` files affect child directories, so this change will block access to whatever directory it's placed in, plus all children. (Until it's overridden by something else.)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ownership of the directory to the `www` or `apache` user, depending on what user your web-server is running as.

Then make sure that the permissions of the directory are set to 644 so that only the owner can write. If you want nobody else to be able to read, just make it 600.

Comment: That wouldn't make them unavailable to users through HTTP as specified. That would affect other local users on the server.

Comment: 600 - nobody can access, even scripts?

Comment: @Alex JL, that´s true, they should definitely be outside of the web server's document root, but when I read `/data/` I kind of assumed that already.

Comment: @Happy, if the user that runs the web-server owns the directory, it can still read and write with permissions 600.

Comment: True, but it's not clear whether `/` refers to the file system root or web server root. I think he means the web server root. Otherwise, they'd already be unavailable.

Comment: @Alex JL, yes, reading the question again, my assumption doesn´t seem quite right...